# How i can pass data with multiple select in select2&laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

i have this to insert in Laravel.

```
 $local = new Local();

        $local->nombre = $pedido->nombre;
        $local->direccion = $pedido->direccion;
        $local->idfamilias = $pedido->seleccion_editar;
        if($pedido->has('id_etiquetas')){
        $local->etiquetas()->sync($pedido->id_etiquetas);
        }
        $local->save();
```

$pedido is the 'Request'. and $local is the model from a table,
in the model i have this

```
public function etiquetas(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Etiquetas','local_etiquetas','id_locales','id_etiquetas');
}
```

to make Relationship many to many.

And i have the Select multiple from Select2 in the view

```
     <select multiple="multiple" name="id_etiquetas[]" id="seleccion_editar_etiquetas" class="form-control selector_etiquetas">
                                @foreach($etiquetas as $etiqueta)
                                    <option value="{{$etiqueta->id}}">{{$etiqueta->nombre}}</option>

                                @endforeach
                            </select>
```

The function etiquetas() of model 'Local' has return this Json:

> [
>     {
>       "id": 1,
>       "idfamilias": 1,
>       "nombre": "qwe",
>       "direccion": "asd",
>       "created_at": null,
>       "updated_at": null,
>       "etiquetas": [
>         {
>           "id": 1,
>           "nombre": "wifi",
>           "created_at": null,
>           "updated_at": null,
>           "pivot": {
>             "id_locales": 1,
>             "id_etiquetas": 1
>           }
>         },
>         {
>           "id": 2,
>           "nombre": "qwe",
>           "created_at": null,
>           "updated_at": null,
>           "pivot": {
>             "id_locales": 1,
>             "id_etiquetas": 2
>           }
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ]

Note:*I pass all the CSRF_TOKEN it works, there's not a problem*

**The table pivot is 'local_etiquetas' and i want to insert, when i try, the console returns POST error 500 internal server error. how can i do it?**

Comment: What is the error message? A HTTP 500 Internal Server error can have very differenct causes. Please include some extended information. Check your Laravel logging and provide some details. Also, what is the `sync()` method on your `etiquetas` object?

Comment: sync() method in laravel are this:https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method Search Syncing Associations

Comment: Okay, but still. We need an error message to help you further. As i said, a HTTP 500 internal server error can have many causes. Please provide some further information on your error.

Comment: [2018-07-30 12:11:10] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_locales' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `local_etiquetas` (`id_etiquetas`, `id_locales`) values (1, )) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_locales' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `local_etiquetas` (`id_etiquetas`, `id_locales`) values (1, ))

Comment: i don't understand why this, i have autoincrement and in the pivot table has got the relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 $local = new Local();
 $local->nombre = $pedido->nombre;
 $local->direccion = $pedido->direccion;
 $local->idfamilias = $pedido->seleccion_editar;
 $local->save();

 if($pedido->has('id_etiquetas')){
     $local->etiquetas()->sync($pedido->id_etiquetas);
 }
```

You are trying to sync the relationship, but the Local model has no ID assigned yet because it is not saved. Try saving it first, so it gets an ID assigned. Then try to sync the relationship.

In  your code:

```
$local = new Local();
$local->nombre = $pedido->nombre;
$local->direccion = $pedido->direccion;
$local->idfamilias = $pedido->seleccion_editar;
if($pedido->has('id_etiquetas')){
    $local->etiquetas()->sync($pedido->id_etiquetas);
} 
// Here, $local does not have an ID yet. So when calling the Sync method an empty ID is passed for $local as it does not exist. 
$local->save();
// Only after the save method is called, your model $local has an ID.
```